# To display stacked value within the stacked bar using jqplot

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, jqplot

I am using jqplot to display graph sales of month.i used horizontal bar graph  for that,i want to display value of each stacked bar within the bar.
   I am tried using following code,

```
        this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {

               renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,

            rendererOptions: {
                shadowOffset: 0,
                  barWidth :'30',
                barDirection: 'horizontal',
                highlightMouseDown: true   
            },
            pointLabels: {show: true ,
                 hideZeros: true,

                 formatString: '%d',

           // xpadding : -90

             xpadding: 20, ypadding: 50,

             // edgeTolerance: -55

            location :'w'


            }
```

but it displayed pointlabels within the bar for 1 st stacked region  correct value displayed but for last it displayed total of stacked bar.
i want to disaplay each region value within the bar not total.
[image]